# awk: assigning a shell variable in awk script

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a situation in `awk` where I need to convert an input format into another format and later use the number of records processed separately. Is there any way I can use a shell variable to get the value of `NR` in the `END section`? Something like:

```
cat file1 | awk 'some processing END{SHELL_VARIABLE=NR}' > file2
```

Then later use SHELL_VARIABLE outside awk.

I do not want to process the file and then do a `wc -l` separately as the files are huge.

Answer (score 3):

One way: Use the redirection inside your [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command and print your result in the `END` block. And use command substitution to read the result in a shell variable:

```
my_var=$(awk '{ some processing; print "your output" >>file2 } END { print NR }' file1)
```

Answer (score 3):

No subprocess can affect the parent's environment variables. What you can do is have `awk` write output to the file directly, then have it print the value you want to stdout and capture it. Or if you prefer, you could reverse that and have awk just print it to a file and read it back afterwards.

Incidentally, you have a UUOC.

```
rows=$(awk '{ ...; print > "file2"} END {print NR}' file1)
```

Or

```
awk '... END{print NR > "rows"}' file1 >file2
rows=$(<rows)
rm rows
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do now. But the problem now is that awk is not able to write the out to a /tmp/ file, but its working in my home dir. Its giving me error: `awk: i/o error occurred on numlines`